# use thread to wait for message from service

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, handler

I have a binded service, which I send message to, and it sends the message back. All this happens in a different class, called **DataItems**.

The main activity calls on DataItems using this method :

```
DataItems.getItems();
```

DataItems will send a message to the service requesting the items, and when it receives a message back (through a handler, it is supposed to send it back to the calling activity).

```
Items results = null;

public Items getItems() {
    sendMessage(); // sends a message to service;
    boolean messageNotReceived = true;
    --> while(messageNotReceived); // wait for message to come back;
    return results;
}


private class CustomHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            results = msg.getData().getParcelable("items");
            messageNotReceived = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the **while loop** will block the thread, and until the while loop is complete, the handleMessage method will not be called. I think that one of them has to be run in a separate thread so as to keep the other unblocked.

If I run the getItems() in a separate thread, how will it return the results back to the calling activity?

```
getItems() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(messageNotReceived);
            // how to return value from here???
        }
    }
    // any operation here will continue in parallel with the thread
    // so any return statements here will be returned to the activity.
}
```

So the problem is how to wait for messages from Service while not blocking the entire thread of execution?

Comment: why are you not doing what you need to after you get a message back inside the handler that gets the message?

Comment: because the scenarios differ for different messages. And its in a library module, so I need to pass the data to the activity rather than put all cases in the handleMessage, which is not possible here.

Comment: Why don't you use AsyncTask where you have doInBackground() and onPsotExecute(). As you may know onPostExecute() will be executed after it finished doInBackground().

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I recommend you to use `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity`. Whenever `handleMessage` is finished, send `Broadcast` to your `Activity`, then you can call `DataItems.getItems();`

Answer (score 0):

Consider including a case in your `handleMessage()` method that checks to see what kind of message your receive. For example:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.getData().getString("sender", "").equals("senderA") {
              // Handle message of type A
        }
        else if (msg.getData().getString("sender", "").equals("senderB") {
              // Handle message of type b
        }
        // ...
}
```

This way your DataItems thread won't have to continuously run while waiting for a response. It will instead be started by a message at precisely the right time.

Comment: and how does this return the data back to the activity that called Data.getItems() ? I think you suggested that I implement a handler in each activity to handle the messages. Which I am precisely avoiding because the handler part is outside the activity in a library.

Comment: @kicker86 I see, it seems I misread your question as asking how to notify DataItems when the service is finished running.  In this case I would recommend eliminating the while loop and, as suggested by Kingfisher, do the following: `void getItems() {sendMessage();}` (no return needed) and in `handleMessage() {// Send broadcast...}`